# Angularjs - $resource GET with arraylist in parameter

Tags: java, angularjs

I would like to make a call to a spring mvc rest service with an array of string in parameters. I have tried this:

```
.factory('CallRequest', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('api/callRequesWithArray/:arrayOfString', {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET', isArray:true,
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                data = angular.fromJson(data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    });
})


@RequestMapping(value = "/callRequesWithArray/{arrayOfString}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET,
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @Timed
    public void envoiBlToClient(@PathVariable ArrayList arrayOfString, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
     ....
    }
```

but it doesnt work, it puts a coma between each of my arraylist items, and then it s not well interpreted (not the way I would like...) and the request is rejected.
Is it possible to pass an array of string in a GET $resource call as a parameter?

Thanks.

Comment: isArray is to return you an array instead an object nothing to do with request params

Comment: I know that, my question is about how to send an array to the spring mvc rest controller.